# "Simplified Varargs Method Invocation" already implemented in the current OpenJDK 7?

Tags: java-7, java

Is "Simplified Varargs Method Invocation" from http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000217.html already implemented in Java 7? Today I read in www.sdtimes.com/INTEGRATION_WATCH_JAVA_7_LOOKING_GOOD/By_ANDREW_BINSTOCK/About_JAVA/34288 about that, but I never found a release note of the JDK 1.7. You have an original quote about that?

Answer (score 0):

At least [now it is in OpenJdk 7](http://www.mail-archive.com/core-libs-dev@openjdk.java.net/msg04314.html).